# Filter cte xpath query

Tags: xpath, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

Given the following XPath CTE I want to filter on `Field2`. How can that be accomplished? I'm just learning XPath. Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
WITH ConvertedToXML AS 
( 
     SELECT TOP 10 
         xml_msg AS AsVarchar,
         CAST(xml_msg AS XML) AS AsXml 
     FROM 
         Table
     ORDER BY
         date_received desc
) 
SELECT 
    ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//Field1)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Field1,
    ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//Field2)[1]', 'Varchar(10)') as Field2,
    ConvertedToXML.AsVarchar,
    ConvertedToXML.AsXml 
Into #TempXML
FROM ConvertedToXML;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to filter rows having `Field2` value equals certain value, `foo` for example, you can do this way :

```
SELECT 
    ......
    ......
Into #TempXML
FROM ConvertedToXML
WHERE ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//Field2)[1]', 'Varchar(10)') = 'foo';
```

Or using XPath predicate to get `Field2` elements having value equals `"foo"`, and use [`exists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method to execute the XPath :

```
SELECT 
    ......
    ......
Into #TempXML
FROM ConvertedToXML
WHERE ConvertedToXML.AsXml.exists('(//Field2[.="foo"])[1]', 'Varchar(10)') = 1;
```